# Cannot embed ternary operator into echo statement

Tags: php, operators, ternary-operator

Here is the `echo` statement:

```
    echo " <a class=\"pagination-link\" href='{$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']}?page=$nextpage#comment-target'> &gt; </a> ";
```

And here is the `ternary expression`. What it does is concatenate the `#comment-target` to the end of the link only if the condition is true:

```
( $paginationAddCommentAnchor ?? null) ? '#comment-target' : null
```

I need to replace in the `echo` statement, `#comment-target` by the `ternary expression`, but every attempt ends up as an ugly ball of mud with wrong quotations. Example attempt:

```
    echo " <a class=\"pagination-link\" href='{$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']}?page=$nextpage . ( $paginationAddCommentAnchor ?? null) ? '#comment-target' : null'> &gt; </a> ";
```

What would be the proper syntax so the final result is the same as the initial `echo` statement, but produced with the ternary?

Comment: `$paginationAddCommentAnchor ?? null` is the same as `$paginationAddCommentAnchor`

Comment: Using multiple lines and variables will make your code a lot easier to read.

Comment: PHP does [variables parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in the strings enclosed by double quotes (`"`) but that's all. If you need to evaluate an expression then you have to put it outside the string and concatenate its value with the surrounding strings using the [string concatenation operator (`.`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: @axiac about your first comment, if I don't put `$paginationAddCommentAnchor ?? null`and the variable is empty it will generate an error.

Comment: @RobertBrax define "empty".

Comment: @axiac I meant not existing

Comment: @RobertBrax "not existing" means ["unset" (or undefined)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) which is the same as [`NULL`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) and [evaluates to `FALSE` in boolean context](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), without any error, warning or notice.

Comment: @axiac : `$commentAnchor =   $paginationAddCommentAnchor  ? '#comment-target' : null ;` => `'Undefined variable: paginationAddCommentAnchor'`

Comment: @RobertBrax You're right, it triggers a notice. You better initialize all the variables with `NULL` (or other value, depending on the variable's purpose) before using them (on top of the script or function or just before the `for`, `if` etc block where they are used for the first time). It helps writing code that is easier to read and understand (and has less errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does [variables parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in the strings enclosed by double quotes (`"`) but that's all. If you need to evaluate an expression then you have to put it outside the string and concatenate its value with the surrounding strings using the [string concatenation operator (`.`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Or, to get more readable code, use [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php):

```
printf(' <a class="pagination-link" href="%s?page=%s%s> &gt; </a> ',
    $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], $nextpage,
    $paginationAddCommentAnchor ? '#comment-target' : ''
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped, I will chose it as an answer. I did as you said and generated the variable outside, then simply concatened it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like trying to do a lot of things in a single line, not controlling correctly all the parts (quotes, string conncatenation, ternary operator...) . To keep things clear and under control, build the final string in separated blocks:

```
$tmp_str = $nextpage . ( $paginationAddCommentAnchor ?? null) ? '#comment-target' : '';

echo "<a class=\"pagination-link\" href=\"{$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']}?page=$tmp_str\"></a>";
```

Test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfed6a3d965a5a18b14a7cf6fe231a14ac5839e3).